# if(File.Exists()) statement isn't working

Tags: c#, winforms

What I want the script to do is show a test saying "Currently Editing: " and then the file path of the folder the if statement is seeing if it exists or not. Even when the file exists, the text still won't pop up. No error messages.

I tried a `File.Exists` if statement, but that won't work, so I don't know what else to try.

```
if (File.Exists(@textBox2.Text + textBox1.Text))
{
    currentlyediting.Text = "Currently Editing: " + textBox2.Text + textBox1.Text;
    currentlyediting.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: This syntax: `if (File.Exists(@textBox2.Text + textBox1.Text))` is wrong. It *could* be something like: `if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(textBox2.Text, textBox1.Text))) { ... }`, but you should say what the TextBoxes contain.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Have you tried finding out the text? Have you tried Path.Combine? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I'd start using System.IO.Path.Combine instead of adding the 2 strings: it will handle for you the nasty "does it ends with folder separator `\`or not"?

Comment: Yes please, what are the values of your textboxes ?

Comment: Basic debug step: what *is* the actual value (as opposed to what you *assume* it should be) of `textBox2.Text + textBox1.Text` (note that you don't need that `@` - it doesn't do what you think it does here)

Comment: Why did I get a downvote, what did I do wrong?

Comment: But anyways, thanks for the comments. Good advice!

Answer (score 2):

You should use recommended `Path.Combine()` method instead of concatenating two or more strings.

Try this instead:

```
var path = Path.Combine(textBox2.Text, textBox1.Text);
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    currentlyediting.Text = $"Currently Editing: {path}";
    currentlyediting.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it soon and accept it if it works!

Comment: @Namerasad Have you considered the timeline where the file `path` doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes, I did put a Thread.Sleep(1000) before the if sentence @John_ReinstateMonica

Comment: @Namerasad what is your `path` value?